# PdfSearchTextExtractor - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, kentico, kentico-12

I'm receiving this error every time I copy, delete pages. Not sure what's causing this error. Any tips to find where the error is being thrown?

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you storing pdf files in media library? Does preview pdf works in that case?

Comment: You have error in the method that extracts PDF content and returns it. When an error occurs, empty string is returned and corresponding exception is logged. I'd say the only way to find out is to debug using jetbrains reshaper.

Comment: I would try applying latest hotfix to exclude already known and fixed issues and then also observe whether it happens for any PDFs or certain only - maybe some PDFs are encrypted or corrupted and these are causing the issue.